# How to prefix country code in Textfield using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, textfield, android-compose-textfield

I want my Textfield to be prefixed with a country code (+91), which can't be changed by the user.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: Two TextFields side by side, where the first one is not editable.

Comment: if you are using android material input layouts then you can find property of prefix and suffix built in

Comment: For uneditable **postfix** (**suffix**) see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74543500/8583692).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

With **M3** `TextField`,starting from `1.1.0-alpha06` you can use the **`prefix`** attribute:

```
    //androidx.compose.material3
    TextField( 
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { text = it },
        prefix = { Text ("+91") }
    )
```

[image]

Before **M3** `1.1.0-alpha06` or with **M2** or you can use the **`visualTransformation`** property:

Something like:

```
TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it},
    visualTransformation = PrefixTransformation("(+91)")
)
```

with:

```
class PrefixTransformation(val prefix: String) : VisualTransformation {    
    override fun filter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {
        return PrefixFilter(text, prefix)
    }
}

fun PrefixFilter(number: AnnotatedString, prefix: String): TransformedText {

    var out = prefix + number.text
    val prefixOffset = prefix.length

    val numberOffsetTranslator = object : OffsetMapping {
        override fun originalToTransformed(offset: Int): Int {
            return offset + prefixOffset
        }

        override fun transformedToOriginal(offset: Int): Int {
            if (offset < prefixOffset) return 0
            return offset - prefixOffset
        }
    }

    return TransformedText(AnnotatedString(out), numberOffsetTranslator)
}
```

[image]

Comment: how to make the code visible (with fade animation) only after the user clicks the textfield?

Answer (score 6):

You can simply add Text() inside leadingIcon parameter inside textField

```
OutlinedTextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = onTextChange,
    maxLines = 1,
    leadingIcon =
    {
        Text(
            text = prefixText,
            style = textStyle,
            color = Color.Black,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 24.dp, end = 8.dp)
        )
    }
)
```

Comment: This is quite nice solution in case there is no need to change the leadingIcon content dynamically. Changing it dynamically changes also the space in between the value and the leadingIcon du to alignment of the leading icon. And it looks clunky in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Another option you could use as well as Gabriele's answer is using the `leadingIcon` property of TextField

```
TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it},
    leadingIcon = {
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_pound_symbol),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    tint = colorResourceFromAttr(id = R.attr.colorOnSurface)
                )
            }
)
```

Which gives you this:

[image: a jetpack compose textfield with pound symbol prefix]