# Jetpack Compose BasicTextField default and undeletable start characters

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I have a BasicTextField that using for phone number with **VisualTransformation** . I can format phone number with VisualTransformation like # ### ### ## ##. But how can I make a BasicTextField that hold first two characters (because in Turkey all of the mobile phone numbers start with 05) and make that caracters undeletable. In other words user can write last 8 characters own phone number. When I give default "05" to **TextFieldValue** , state value is overriding that default value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
But you probably want to use onValueChange and add prefix

Comment: @Милош Којадиновић yes absolutely

Comment: Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67735208/how-to-prefix-country-code-in-textfield-using-jetpack-compose/67735317#67735317