# How to add uneditable postfix (suffix) to TextField in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, textfield, android-jetpack, android-compose-textfield

How can I add a suffix to `TextField` input that flows (moves) with the user input text?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With **M3** starting from the `1.1.0-alpha06` you can use the **`suffix`** attribute:

```
    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { text = it },
        suffix = { Text ("€") }
    )
```

[image]

Before **M3** `1.1.0-alpha06` or with **M2** or you can use the **`visualTransformation`** attribute.

Something like:

```
TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    singleLine = true,
    visualTransformation = SuffixTransformation(" €"),
)

class SuffixTransformation(val suffix: String) : VisualTransformation {
    override fun filter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {

        val result = text + AnnotatedString(suffix)

        val textWithSuffixMapping = object : OffsetMapping {
            override fun originalToTransformed(offset: Int): Int {
                return offset
            }

            override fun transformedToOriginal(offset: Int): Int {
                if (text.isEmpty()) return 0
                if (offset >=  text.length) return text.length                    return offset
            }
        }

        return TransformedText(result, textWithSuffixMapping )
    }
}
```

[image]

If you have the placeholder you can put a condition in the `visualTransformation` attribute.

Something like:

```
TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    singleLine = true,
    visualTransformation = if (text.isEmpty())
        VisualTransformation.None
    else
        SuffixTransformation(" €"),
    placeholder = { Text("Placeholder") }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this was a self-answered question. I think you didn't notice that :) What do you think of my answer? Actually, I derived it from [one of your posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67735317/8583692)!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, very useful  (just check the suggestion of Martynas B, it's right.)

If it can be useful to someone, I use this code to avoid overlapping  when using BasicTextField with placeholder :
`
        var suffixLocal: String = "" // avoid to overlap placeholder

        if (!text.isEmpty()) suffixLocal = suffix

        val result:AnnotatedString = text + AnnotatedString(suffixLocal)
        val suffixOffset = suffixLocal.length
`

Comment: @android_dev71 thanks for the feedback. I've update the answer with the placeholder scenario. I would prefer to put a condition in the `visualTransformation` attribute just to have more flexibility. For example you can also handle the focus state with a placeholder.

Comment: what is M3 and im not able to see any suffix property i can see only trailingIcon which accepts a compose object

Comment: @Praneeth https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti how can I do this? when I try I'm able to see only trailingIcon and its adding some padding and looks weird for my suffix icon

Answer (score 2):

I found Gabriele Mariotti's answer buggy. Needed to change `transformedToOriginal` function to this:

```
override fun transformedToOriginal(offset: Int): Int {
    if (offset > text.length) return text.length
    return offset
}
```

Comment: it's right, without this correction it gives errors like this, in my case happens with 2 fields, moving cursor by clicking from one to another o something else: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: OffsetMapping.transformedToOriginal returned invalid mapping: 5 -> 5 is not in range of original text [0, 4]`

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done in [Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose) like this:

```kotlin
const val SUFFIX = " $"
@Composable
fun SuffixedText() {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    TextField(
        text,
        singleLine = true,
        visualTransformation = SuffixTransformer(SUFFIX),
        onValueChange = { text = it }
    )
}
```

```kotlin
class SuffixTransformer(val suffix: String) : VisualTransformation {
    override fun filter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {
        val result = text + AnnotatedString(suffix)
        return TransformedText(result, OffsetMapping.Identity)
    }
}
```

The above component probably can be used in traditional **View**s too. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69232901/8583692)

Also, see the following:

- [How to add a **prefix** to a `TextField` in **Compose**?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67735317/8583692)
- [GitHub issue to add flowing suffix in **View**s in Material components for Android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/750)
- [Put constant text inside EditText in **View** which should be non-editable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14195207/8583692)

Comment: It has some issues. For example if you click in the suffix (inside o just after the last character) the code crashed because of OffsetMapping.Identity

Comment: I tied it in a Desktop app using [Compose Multiplatform](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb) v1.2.1 which uses Compose v??? on Windows and did not encounter any error. Maybe it's a regression in newer versions of Compose?