# How to suffix text to OutlinedTextField

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Hello I have a OutlinedTextField, and I want to add text to end of it so it is always there.

```
   OutlinedTextField(
                    value = screenState.batterySize.toString(),
                    onValueChange = onBatterySizeChange,
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
                    textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1.copy(
                        color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                    )
                )
```

I tried Suffix but that did not work.

lets if the user types 200, km should be there always, so should look "200 km"

any suggestions on how I can achieve that please
thank you
R

## EDIT

how I tried to add suffix
when I added suffix like this:

```
  OutlinedTextField(
                value = screenState.batterySize.toString(),
                onValueChange = onBatterySizeChange,
                suffix = Text(text = "test"),
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
                textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1.copy(
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                )
            )
```

I get this error:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
OutlinedTextField(TextFieldValue, (TextFieldValue) → Unit, Modifier = ..., Boolean = ..., Boolean = ..., TextStyle = ..., (() → Unit)? = ..., (() → Unit)? = ..., (() → Unit)? = ..., (() → Unit)? = ..., Boolean = ..., VisualTransformation = ..., KeyboardOptions = ..., KeyboardActions = ..., Boolean = ..., Int = ..., MutableInteractionSource = ..., Shape = ..., TextFieldColors = ...) defined in androidx.compose.material
OutlinedTextField(String, (String) → Unit, Modifier = ..., Boolean = ..., Boolean = ..., TextStyle = ..., (() → Unit)? = ..., (() → Unit)? = ..., (() → Unit)? = ..., (() → Unit)? = ..., Boolean = ..., VisualTransformation = ..., KeyboardOptions = ..., KeyboardActions = ..., Boolean = ..., Int = ..., MutableInteractionSource = ..., Shape = ..., TextFieldColors = ...) defined in androidx.compose.material
```

Comment: This might be helpful - [how-to-add-uneditable-postfix-suffix-to-textfield-in-jetpack-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74543500/how-to-add-uneditable-postfix-suffix-to-textfield-in-jetpack-compose)

Comment: What does it mean it didn't work ?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I updated the question with what I tried.

Comment: Make sure you are using material 3, version 1.1.0 or above. And `suffix` takes a Composable, not a String.

Comment: @RickyMo I tried `suffix = Text(text = "test")` as well but same error, I am using material 2, is that an issue,

Comment: @BRDroid material 2 doesn't have the `suffix` parameter. See the post in the first comment.

Answer (score 1):

We don't have `prefix` and `suffix` in the Material 3
but you can use this code if you want prefix text or suffix text or
anything at the start and end of your `OutLineTextField`:
if you want a prefix you can use leadingIcon

```
leadingIcon = {
   Text(text = "Click", Modifier.clickable {
     Log.d("click", "clicked")
    })       
 }
```

and for suffixes, you can use trailingIcon

```
trailingIcon= {
   Text(text = "Click", Modifier.clickable {
        Log.d("click", "clicked")
   })       
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use a combination of OutlinedTextField and a separate Text component.

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
) {
    var textFieldValue by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = textFieldValue,
        onValueChange = { textFieldValue = it },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
        textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1.copy(
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        ),
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
    )
    
    Text(
        text = "km",
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 8.dp)
    )
}
```

we use a Row layout to place the OutlinedTextField and Text components side by side. The OutlinedTextField is assigned a value and an onValueChange callback to manage the input text. The Text component is used to display the constant "km" text. By adjusting the Modifier.padding and other styling attributes, you can further customize the appearance of the components to fit your needs.

Comment: Why you should use a Text outside the OutlinedTextField instead of using the suffix attribure?

Comment: alternative way !